# Как отправить эфемеральное сообщение нажавшему на кнопку? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, button

[image: Это эфемеральное сообщение]

**Вот у меня есть код создающий кнопку которая должна отправлять текст (эфемеральный)**

```
class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label='Send Message', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def menu1(self, integration:discord.Integration, button:discord.ui.Button):
        await integration.send(f"Hello i'm from **{integration.guild}**", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    view = Menu()
    await ctx.reply(view=view)
```

(как правильно написать отправление участнику сообщение?)

Comment: добавил картинку  эфемерального сообщения

Comment: `как правильно написать отправление участнику сообщение?` А что здесь неправильного? Что-то не работает?

Comment: Все должно работать